# Can I use present with should have pp

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

> I **know** I should have waited a little longer but I **can't wait**.

Is it possible to use present simple tense ("I know") with "should have" (modal verb)?

Comment: What do "pp" stands for? (present progressive?)

Answer (score 1):

*should have* shows that you didn't do the action. Instead, you did something else. So after this, the past tense follows:

> *I know I should've waited a little longer but I **couldn't** wait.*

*know* can also be substituted by *knew*, and the difference is clear.

---

With a little more of context, this can also works:

> *I know I should've waited a little longer but I can't wait till tomorrow!*